# Does everyone use hugepage on clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse, huge-pages

It invalid When I enable hugepage on clickhouse (version: v21.9.2.17-stable). The enable hugepage action is:

echo 'madvise' | sudo tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/tips/

Does everyone use hugepage on clickhouse success?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'madvise' | sudo tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
madvise

$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always [madvise] never
```

```
$ echo 'never' | sudo tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
never

cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]
```

Comment: The config is valid:

`cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled

always [madvise] never`

and conside clickhouse use jemalloc to manager memory. I also set MALLOC_CONF to enable thp.

`export MALLOC_CONF=thp:always,metadata_thp:always `